# Can Paragon Surge be cast on a familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spellcasting, races, familiars

[Familiars](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar) have the Share Spells ability, allowing spells with special targeting rules to be cast on them:

> Share Spells: The wizard may cast a spell with a target of “You” on his familiar (as a touch spell) instead of on himself. A wizard may cast spells on his familiar even if the spells do not normally affect creatures of the familiar’s type (magical beast).

I'm fairly sure this allows, say, [Reduce Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-person/) to be cast on a Familiar. But can it let you cast a spell that you could not target yourself with on your familiar? I'm particularly interested in [Paragon Surge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/paragon-surge), as giving my familiar any feat that it meets the prerequisites for sounds useful.

I'm fairly sure the question is just whether Paragon Surge's Range of Personal (half-elf only) means you can only cast it if you are a half-elf, or only target it if you are a half-elf, but I'm not sure if that's the issue.

If it matters, I have an [Improved Familiar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar/), [Small Earth Elemental](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-earth/small-earth-elemental/), and I am a witch, but I'm mostly curious about the general hypothetical. Share Spells mentions magical beasts, which the Earth Elemental is not, but I assume that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You need to be able  to target yourself to share the spell

You can only target the familiar if you could target yourself with the spell. The Share Spells ability says:

> The wizard may cast a spell with a target of “You” on his familiar (as a touch spell) **instead of on himself**.

If the wizard cannot cast the spell on himself, he cannot cast it on the familiar *instead of* himself. Instead by dictionary means:

> as an alternative or substitute

If there is no legal target in the wizard to begin with, there is nothing to substitute.